# Cleaning matte - remove areas smaller than x pixels?

Tags: after-effects

I have created a plate through the "difference matte" process - but I have a bunch of area's that show small white speckles on a black background. Is there an automated way to remove those small white dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding a matte choker should do what you need. You can expand the matte using this effect.